# Write a program that inputs an integer (0 - 9999) and outputs the number of digits. Output should have digit and digits

Tags: python

> Write a program that inputs an integer (0 - 9999) and outputs the number of digits.
>
> Ex: If the input is: `7493`
>
> The output is: `4 digits`
>
> If the input is: `7`
>
> The output is: `1 digit`

My code:

```
num = int(input())
count = 0

while num != 0:
    num //= 10
    count += 1

print(str(count), 'digits')
```

Here is the output I am getting:

[image: output]

I have two questions:

1. Why does my program calculate 0 instead of 1 as the number of digits of the input "0"?
2. How can I create different output "digit" or "digits", depending on whether the input number has 1 digit or more than 1 digit?

Comment: You were given numerous correct answers, why didn't you select one? That's what the big gray checkmark to the left of an answer is for. Not selecting the answer that helped you most, will eventually lead to nobody helping you. We can easily click your name and see if you accept answers. I do that before I even bother to answer. I would not currently help you. Helping you would just screw up my stats on how often my answer is selected as "the" answer. You make it a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple test:

```
num = input()
answer = str(len(num)) + ' digit'
if len(num) > 1:
    answer += 's'
print(answer)
```

You can simplify the test this way:

```
num = input()
print(str(len(num)) + ' digit' + ('s' if len(num)>1 else ''))
```

And even more (though that's debatable in terms of readability):

```
num = input()
print(str(len(num)) + ' digit' + 's' * (len(num)>1))
```

And now, all the way into the realm of short and obscure :) :

```
print(str(length := len(input())) + ' digit' + 's' * (length>1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a minimum of 1 at the very end and then a binary expression for digit(s).

```
num = int(input())
count = 0

while num != 0:
    num //= 10
    count += 1

count = max(count, 1)


print(str(count), 'digit' + 's' if count > 1 else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate ternary:

```
print(count:=len(input()),'digit'+('','s')[count>1])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of digits, just leverage on the base 10 logarithm.

```
import math as m
m.ceil(m.log10(x + 1))
```

The ceiling is necessary to round up the result to the correct answer, because the log_10 will give you (almost) always one digit less. The +1 is to consider limit cases as the exact power of 10.

The complete version would be:

```
def nb_digits(x: int) -> str:
    plural = 's' if x >= 10 else ''
    return f'{m.ceil(m.log10(int(x) + 1))} digit{plural}'
```

The `x: int` is a type hint (does not force typing). Eventually, you can enforce the input at the return line with `int(x)`.

The `plural` in the interpolated string should be obvious.

Usage example:

```
>>> nb_digits(7493)
'4 digits'
>>> nb_digits(7)
'1 digit'
```